# I'm not able to access the close button through keyboard

Tags: javascript, css, accessibility

I'm not able to access the close image button through keyboard even I've added `tabindex=0` in `<img src= "close img link" tabindex="0" alt= "close" title="close" aria-labelledby="close" />`

It is just getting Focus through keyboard but it not able to close by space and enter button on keyboard

Comment: You'll have to provide some more context and some code in the form of a [mcve]. For example: is this close button on a modal? Are you expecting the element to be closed to be be closed with or without JavaScript? What have you tried?

Comment: It is actually popup close button arrow mark and I've tried without Java script and by adding <span class="popupclose"><img src="/images/icons/popup-close.svg"  tabindex="0" alt="close" title="close" aria-label="close" aria-hidden="true"></span>

Comment: It is actually popup close button arrow mark and I've tried without Java script and by adding <span class="popupclose"><img src="/images/icons/popup-close.svg" tabindex="0" alt="close" title="close" aria-label="close" aria-hidden="true"></span>

Answer (score 2):

I assume because you have used an `aria-` attribute, as well as been able to close with space, your also wanting to make accessible.

Each element on a page has a role, which communicates to users of assistive technology what they can expect from that element. The `<img>` element has the role of an image, which is not an interactive element. The expected role would be that of a `button`.

The `<button>` is then automatically accessible, in that it already receives focus and fires the `click` event when <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

You must then add `aria-label` to it, to provide an *accessible name*, so that users known what they are doing.

Because the `svg` <strike>`img`</strike> then has no more meaning for accessibility, you can then also mark this with `aria-hidden="true"`

Below is a working snippet, I've used an inline SVG, but using an IMG will be the same.

updated: As noted in comments by slugolicious, for an img tag you can set `alt=""` instead.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.image_button');
const frm = document.querySelector('.form');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => frm.remove());
```

```css
.image_button {
  padding: 3px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.image_button svg {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: block;
}

.form {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <p>The close button below can be closed via keyboard, and should also be screen reader friendly.  For keyboard user, press TAB to highlight and press SPACE to close.</p>

  Close me -> 
  
  <button aria-label="close" class="image_button">
    <svg 
      aria-hidden="true"
      viewPort="0 0 12 12" version="1.1"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <line x1="0" y1="12" x2="12" y2="0" 
              stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="12" y2="12" 
              stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/>
    </svg>
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: If you have a real <img> embedded in a button, use `alt=""` to "hide" the image rather than `aria-hidden` since alt is required on an <img>. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#alt

Comment: @slugolicious  Thanks, I'll add that to comments..

Comment: `<svg>` does not have an `alt` attribute, I removed it from the post. (:

Comment: It is actually popup close button arrow mark and I've tried without Java script and by adding <span class="popupclose"><img src="/images/icons/popup-close.svg" tabindex="0" alt="close" title="close" aria-label="close" aria-hidden="true"></span> but it is getting Focus but not getting close through space and enter button